# How to insert records by updating two fields?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Table with 5 fields. among 5 columns one is PK. my reqt is i need to get rows based on some column(non duplicated but not PK) and for all returned results i need to assign new PK and save.

If i have 10 records in my table. if i get 10 records based on certain column. i need to asssign new PK for all 10 records and save. Finally there will be 20 records in the table. is there any single SQL query which does this operation?

Thanks!

Comment: ys it is possible , but for that you need to show ur pk making logic and the table schema

Comment: If you are sure there are no collisions, you can use a sequence and generate a PK with sequence_name.NEXTVAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF col1 is PK (for autoincrement column)

```
insert into table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) 
    select null, col2, col3, col4, col5 
    from table 
    where col2 = 'anyvalue' and more conditions... ;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
--  create a sequence to manage the primary keys
create sequence key_sequence;

--  i don't know what data you want in your table
create table tempTable (
myKey int primary key,
myValue varchar(12))

--  create four rows of arbitrary data, they will get primary keys of 1,2,3 and 4
insert into tempTable values (key_sequence.nextval, 'eggs')
insert into tempTable values (key_sequence.nextval, 'bacon')
insert into tempTable values (key_sequence.nextval, 'chips')
insert into tempTable values (key_sequence.nextval, 'salad')

--  you can see the 4 rows
select * from tempTable

--  select all four rows (as no where clause) and re-insert them into the table
--  the sequence will take care of allocating new primary keys
insert into tempTable
select  key_sequence.nextval, myValue 
from    tempTable

--  now you can see eight rows in the table
select * from tempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood you correctly but would this do what you need?

As you haven't given much detail, you'll have to fill in the blanks!

```
INSERT INTO <table> (
   pk_col,
   col2,
   col3,
   col4,
   col5
)
   SELECT <new_pk>,
          col2,
          col3,
          col4,
          col5
     FROM <table>
    WHERE <your search criteria>;
```

Hope it helps...